# Brave Browser overwrites my CSS styles , How to avoid?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, browser, cross-browser, brave-browser

I have developed a website in Bootsratp 4
When I tested my side in Brave browser. Some of the features are not working.
But the same is working in other browsers.
How to avoid this?
Whiile inspecting I am getting this

```
.sideads {
    display: none !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Which bootstrap classes aren't working?

Comment: @MMM this is not bootstrap class this is custom class

Answer (score 0):

It seems that brave has a heuristic that blocks any class that contains the word ad/ads

You can go to settings (`brave://settings/shields`) and disable the *trackers and add blocking*

[image]